# Ubuntu 12.04 Boot Freeze At Purple Screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

In the last week or so Ubuntu has started freezing on boot, showing only a purple screen. It freezes before the screen saying Ubuntu with small dots under it comes up. The keyboard and mouse doesn't seem to respond to anyting and nothing happens if I just wait some time.

It seems to be coming at almost random but usually with a few days in between.
I have been running Ubuntu since it was first released and before the freezes started happening I had no problems at all. But now when I hover an application in the launcher bar, the popup with the name on it will sometimes act weird or not show properly. I don't know if that has anything to do with the freezing.

Any help? Thanks.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Bumblebee and only a few other applications installed. My computer is a Samsung Q330:

Intel® Core™ i3 Processor 330M (2.13 GHz, 3 MB)
4GB (DDR3 / 2GB x 2)
nVIDIA GeForce 310M
320 GB (5400 opm S-ATA)

Comment: Try doing a memory test?

Answer (score 0):

try "sudo update-grub" (without quotes)when you have booted in terminal
also try hitting arrow down or arrow left on your keyboard when grub enter load your ubuntu
that will show you a text message about grub processes
see if that something wrong with your grub
or you can simply enter "gksu xdiagnose"(without quotes) in terminal
then checklist all the checkbox except the first one
hope that can solve your problem